# XPath to get link text inside span with newline characters

Tags: javascript, xpath, hyperlink

I'm trying to extract with Javascript the name of an href inside a span of a flickr photo page, the source looks like:

```
    <span class="photo-name-line-1">                    
        <a href="/photos/humpty_dumpty/">
                                Humpty Dumpty
                        </a>
    </span>
```

I seem to get the object but cannot extract the text to use in JavaScript:

```
        // get the span that contains user name              
        photoname = document.evaluate("//span[@class='photo-name-line-1']/a/text()",
            document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
            null).singleNodeValue;

        alert('debug ' + photoname);
```

My debug statement returns [Object Text] but I cannot get it as a variable I can use in Javascript. have tried `photoname.value` `photoname.InnerText` but all return `undefined`

I suspect its an issue of the line breaks; but I have not been able to implement `normalize-space()` to get anything.

I'm looking for the code to get me a JS variable with a value of `Humpty Dumpty`- (pretty new to Xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `.textContent` value.

```
alert('debug ' + photoname.textContent);
```

Comment: Thanks that nailed it! Actually photoname.textContent.trim() gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: Thanks, I am obviously a Stack Newbie